# How do you spawn a giant?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to spawn a giant until i found out that there's a spawn egg of a giant but it didn't work. I've tried it with Not Many Items and it did not work

Comment: Why is this tagged "achievements"?

Comment: i got mess up =P

Answer (score 5):

Giants were in minecraft for a very short time appearing in the early life of the game (like alpha). They have since been removed and will not spawn naturally. The legacy code still remains. Because of this, some mods will reenable the spawning of Giants, but you then see why they were removed.

answer: you cant spawn giants without mods.

Comment: This is interesting and all, but not really an answer.

Comment: theres the answer. which is what I was saying.

Answer (score 4):

You can spawn giants by using the `/summon` command in the latest version.

Comment: I think the OP wants to summon the Giant in the regular way (and not with command)

Comment: @WizLiz There is no "regular" way. Giants are not part of the game. They're part of unused content that just hasn't ever been removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple and easy to spawn a giant, I have used this method many times, just type /summon giant It's that easy!

Answer (score -2):

```
/summon Giant
```

Also I think this works, I'm not sure.

With Diamond Armor:

```
/summon Giant ~ ~1 ~ {Equipment:[{},{id:diamond_boots},{id:diamond_leggings},{id:diamond_chestplate},{id:diamond_helmet}],PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}],Riding:{id:"Bat",PersistenceRequired:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:2147483647}]}}
```